# How to disable Error Validation messages in a grid with MVC4 asp .net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I work with asp .net MVC4 and Telerik. I have in the same page a form and a grid. I'd like to hide the validation messages **in my grid only** when I insert or update a row. But, if it's possible, preserve the coloring on the input-field. Theses messages are automatically displayed without any `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`

[image]

They are displayed when I submit and every time I click on a new field so I don't know where can I "catch" the event and delete the desired `<span>`.

Do you know how to deal with these messages ?

Comment: Just remove them from the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of the API of the Telerik thing you are using, but a workaround could be to style the error `<span />` in your CSS. I.e. something like:

```
.t-grid .field-validation-error {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok... I find the answer with `.t-grid .field-validation-error { display: none; }` which hides only the fields from the grid. Thank you, sounds obvious now ! :)

Answer (score 0):

In css u call style property in span tag

```
<span class="text-danger" style="display:none">Invalid Email Id</span>
```